# In "hellogl2" example from Qt 5.4.1 on Windows XP i see black sliders. Why?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, windows-xp

Qt example "hellogl2", compiled with Qt 5.4.1 32bit, works fine on Windows 8.1. But on Windows XP some widgets are black, as in [this screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3zvBbPGn7mFTXpZVnhPNDItWFE/view?usp=sharing). Widgets are rendered incorrectly with OpenGL version of Qt, and with ANGLE. I use MSVC 2010 compiler. A similar example from Qt 4.8.6 is working properly. My GPU is GeForce 7600 GS, but I'm pretty sure that the error is not related to the standard opengl32.dll and driver from Nvidia. I have compiled a Mesa3d library for Windows using the llvmpipe driver, implementing software rendering. When I put opengl32.dll from Mesa3d in a folder with the hellogl2 executable file, nothing has changed (I'm sure that the library was loaded, because I noticed decrease in the number of frames per second). In some other examples with OpenGL widgets and windows are also displayed incorrectly (although similar examples with Qt4 work well). I found out that widgets are displayed normally only if the system is set to "Classic Style" (like in Windows 98).
How can I solve this problem? Am I doing something wrong? Or is it a flaw in the example?

Comment: Is only this example affected, or also other examples with sliders in it?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld "40000 Chips" example works as expected. All the controls are drawn normally (even sliders). You can see it on [this screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3zvBbPGn7mFYzBQUDB4OHhzTGM/view?usp=sharing).